# Cannot run mongo shell script on several million of data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have a script in mongoshell that should populate a collection (dataaggregation) from another one (data), aggregating the timeseries for each 5 minutes.
The data collection has 7.000.000+ entries and the script takes ages to complete... 8h for 500.000 data to be taken into account and it seems frozen now.

Basically the data collection has records like:

```javascript
{
  isodate: '2014-12-1OT12:47:32.000+02.00',
  value: 234,
  parentID: 123      
}
```

The dataaggreagtion collection has records like:

```javascript
{
   t: '2014-12-1OT12:45:00.000+02.00',
   pid: 123,  // parentID
   sum: 1234, // sum of all the value of data between 12:45 and 12:50
   count: 5,  // number of data elements between 12:45 and 12:50
   min: 23,   
   max: 435
}
```

Each record of the data collection will be part of a record of the dataaggregation collection (will count for 1 in the count attribute).

```javascript
// Cleanup collection
db.dataaggregation.remove({})

// Loop through data and populate the dataaggregation collection
db.data.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(function(dt){
  // Get 5 minutes timestamp
  // eg: '2014-12-1OT12:47:32.000+02.00' => '2014-12-1OT12:45:00.000+02.00'
  dt.isodate.setMinutes(dt.isodate.getMinutes() - dt.isodate.getMinutes() % 5);
  dt.isodate.setSeconds(0);

  // Create the dataaggregation record for the (timestamp, parentID) couple if does
  // not exist or update the existing one
  var d = db.dataaggregation.findOne({t: dt.isodate, pid: dt.parentID});
  if(!d){
    db.dataaggregation.insert({
        t:dt.isodate,
        pid: dt.parentID,
        sum: dt.value,
        count: 1,
        min: dt.value,
        max: dt.value
    });
  }else{
    db.dataaggregation.update({
        t:dt.isodate,
        pid: dt.parentID
    },{
        $set:{
            sum: d.sum + dt.value,
            count: d.count + 1,
            min: dt.value < d.min ? dt.value : d.min,
            max: dt.value > d.max ? dt.value : d.max
        }
    },
    {upsert:true}
    );
  }
})
```

Any idea or suggestion to improve this ? Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for this? The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline does this along with [other operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) to handle your calculations.

You would probably need a MongoDB 2.6 or greater server version to do so though. I would suggest running this, turning on the "allowDiskUse" option an using the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline stage to write the collection.

The first thing you are going to need to do here is convert all your "string" data in dates to real [`Date`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) objects. This is fairly simple to do and well referenced here on StackOverflow as it is a common modelling mistake.

Probably the most simple way to do this is with basic "date math". Date objects in MongoDB respond to math operations against other date objects by returning a "epoch timestamp" value (when subtracted from the epoch date itself, otherwise it's just a number with the milliseconds difference). This makes intervals simple:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "t": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$isoDate", new Date("1970-01-01") },
                    { "$subtract": [
                       { "$isoDate", new Date("1970-01-01") },
                       { "$mod": [
                           { "$isoDate", new Date("1970-01-01") },
                           1000 * 60 * 5
                       ]}
                    ]}                          
                ]
            },
            "pid": "$parentID"
        },
        "sum": { "$sum": "$value" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "min": { "$min": "$value" },
        "max": { "$max": "$value" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "t": "$_id.t",
        "pid": "$_id.pid",
        "sum": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1
    }},
    { "$out": "dataaggregation" }
],{ "allowDiskUse": true })
```

Or use similar operations using the date aggregation operators:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "t": {
                "year": { "$year": "$isodate" },
                "month": { "$month": "$isodate" },
                "dayOfMonth": { "$dayOfMonth": "$isodate" },
                "hour": { "$hour": "$isodate" },
                "minute": {
                    "$mod": [
                        { "$minute": "$isodate" },
                        5
                    ]
                }
            },
            "pid": "$parentID"
        },
        "sum": { "$sum": "$value" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "min": { "$min": "$value" },
        "max": { "$max": "$value" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "t": "$_id.t",
        "pid": "$_id.pid",
        "sum": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1
    }},
    { "$out": "dataaggregation" }
],{ "allowDiskUse": true })
```

Long winded, but it depends on the output you want. In either case the basic approach is to use the modulo [**`$mod`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) operator in order to determine the 5 minute intervals from the numeric results provided in each case.

Either way you don't get a `Date` object back in the result, but you do get something that can be easily "cast" into a `Date` object.

You could optionally drop the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline if you can live with the "dataaggregation" collection having a compound `_id` field in place of separate fields for "t" and "pid" as well to make that more efficient still.

As long as your server can handle it then it's going to run a lot faster than transferring to the client and writing back to the database.

---

Just for addition, here is an approach to "cast" all your strings as dates using the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/):

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderdBulkOp();
var counter = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id })
        .updateOne({ "$set": { "isodate": new Date(doc.isodate) } });
    counter++;

    if( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderdBulkOp();
    }  
});

if ( counter % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you group the timestamps so each data goes in the correct 5 minutes bucket ? For example, 2014-12-1OT12:47:32.000+02.00 should go in the dataaggregation  referenced by:  1. the same parentID as the original data record; 2. the following timestamp 2014-12-1OT12:45:00.000+02.00

Comment: @Luc That can be done fairly easily with the aggregation. But in all fairness that is not the question that you asked here. If you have another question then it is best to ask another question. I makes your intent clear on a per question basis and as a rule the StackExchange model is "one question only" per response. Date math or date aggregation operators is the hint. If you cannot figure that out then "ask another question". This one has been answered as long as aggregation is appropriate to use rather than a client coded response.

Comment: That was a hidden part of my question (that was in the comment of the code) but you'r right I was not that clear though :)

Comment: @Luc go on and give it a try. The hint was given. But if you cannot work it out or are impatient, then I await your new question :)

Comment: humm I kinda validated too fast :) I ran the script but got a dataaggregation entry for each of the data entry that I have (count=1, sum=min=max='value of the data"). That is normal as the (isodate, parentID) couple is unique in the data collection. The grouping I was expecting is really each 5 minutes so the sum, min, max, count are updated with all the records having a timestamp in that timeframe. I will update the title that may not be too details.

Comment: @Luc Very well. Altered listings to group times as 5 minute intervals. This really comes out like "three answers in one", but you had no way of knowing that at the time of asking. So not your fault.

Comment: @Neil-Lunn, I believe you dont test your codes, you write what comes to your mind and it will always works fine, how? nice work dude

Answer (score 2):

As Neil proposed, i suggest you to use Mongo aggregation.
If you want to aggregate data all the 5 minutes, you can use :

```
db.data.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "t": { $subtract: [{ $subtract: [ "$isodate", { $multiply: [{ $mod: [ {$minute:"$isodate"}, 5 ] }, 60*1000]} ] }, { $multiply: [{ $mod: [ {$second:"$isodate"}, 60 ] }, 1000]}]},
            "pid": "$variableID"
        },
        "sum": { "$sum": "$value" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "min": { "$min": "$value" },
        "max": { "$max": "$value" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "t": "$_id.t",
        "pid": "$_id.pid",
        "sum": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1
    }},
{ "$out": "dataaggregation" }
],{ "allowDiskUse": true })
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say why it is slow, but a couple of things I noticed/would have done differently:

- Use $inc instead of $set to increment count and sum
- Create a combined index on t and pid

You could also consider reading data ordered by isodate and then only write a 5 minute bucket to MongoDB once you reach a new 5 minute bucket. That would greatly reduce the amount of reads  and writes to your aggregated collection.